# Where is this webhook administered in the DO dashboard or API?

Tags: gitlab, webhooks, digital-ocean

I inherited an app that uses Gitlab push webhooks to initiate deploy to DO. Unfortunately, I have no clue where this is configured in the DO dashboard.

The Gitlab webhook is pointed at https://apps-inbound.digitalocean.com/webhooks/gitlab.

Can someone help me understand where the DigitalOcean side of this webhook is configured or where the docs are please?

Thanks for reading.

I've tried Google, reading the API docs, looking for the URI components in the site, etc but I haven't found anything yet.